Approximating continuous functions by smooth functions
Consider a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$. I want a family $(f_t)_{0<t<1}$ of smooth functions, such that $f_0=f$ in the $\sup$-norm. I know this can be done with the choice of a mollifier for example $$\phi(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{I_n}\exp\left(\frac{1}{1-\|x\|^2}\right)& \|x\|<1\\\\
0 & \|x\|\ge 1\end{cases}$$
Then we can take $f_t=f\ast \phi_t$ where $\phi_t(x)=\frac{1}{t^n}\phi(x/t)$ then $f_t$ is smooth and $f_t\to f$ in the sup norm. But I am looking for something more specific, where I also want $0$ to not be a critical value of the $f_t$'s, i.e. if $f_t(x)=0$ then $df_t(x)\ne 0$ for every $t>0$. I'm not sure if this is true. So if someone can show how to prove it in this case, or if it isn't true for this example of $f_t$'s can you show me how to construct an example of $f_t$'s such that $0$ is not a critical value. If it helps, the example of $f$ that I'm specifically interested in is $$f(x)=\min_{1\le i\le N}a_i^Tx+b_i$$ where $f(x)=0$ determines a (bounded) polytope.
Edit : I'm not sure if this requires some different sort of distance for it to work, but what I really want is a family of smooth submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary which has the polytope as a limit shape. So if you are familiar with examples for that, I would be grateful. As a commenter points out, this may be false as stated, but I would be happy as long as I can get some family of submanifolds approximating my polytope.

Do you want f be like a signed distance function of a convex domain? With Lipschitz assumption this is more concrete to be handled. Otherwise the question is too vague as there are easy counterexamples.

I'm not familiar with the signed distance function. I would like to see such an example of approximations. If you want concreteness, then you may assume the example I've given. I will edit the question.

I guess you need $f$ to be "transversal". Otherwise take $f$ vanishing on an open set, the generic mollification cannot guarantee $df_t|_{(f_t=0)}\neq0$.

Okay, fair point. But this isn't happening when the function in question is a minimum of a bunch of lines. But I would be happy to have other way to approximate this, check the edits.

Let me put the update at front.
Let us consider a bounded Lipschitz domain $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^n$. We consider a Lipschitz defining function of $\Omega$, which is a Lipschitz function $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ such that

$\Omega=\{x:f(x)<0\}$ and $\overline\Omega^c=\{x:f(x)>0\}$. In particular $\partial\Omega=(f=0)$.

There is a $\eta_0>0$ and continuous vector field $X:(-\eta_0<f<\eta_0)\to\Bbb R^n$ such that $X(x)\cdot\nabla f(x)>\eta_0$ for almost every $x\in(-\eta_0<f<\eta_0)$.


In the case where $\Omega$ and $f$ are both $C^1$, then the second condition is equivalent as $\nabla f(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in \partial\Omega$.
It's important to notice that if $\Omega_1,\dots,\Omega_m$ are all $C^1$ domains with $C^1$ defining functions $f_1,\dots,f_m$, then $\max_{1\le i\le m}f_i$ is a Lipschitz defining function for $\bigcap_{i=1}^m\Omega_i$.
Back to the old answer:
One can check that the signed distance function is a defining function. Let $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^n$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain, the signed distance is $\delta(x)=\operatorname{dist}(x,\Omega)$ if $x\in\Omega^c$ and $\delta(x)=-\operatorname{dist}(x,\Omega^c)$ if $x\in\Omega$. In some literature there would be a flip of the sign.
We claim that when $f=\delta$ and $f_t=\phi_t\ast f$ satisfy what you need. I don't have a short proof here so I only sketch the proof.
The key is to notice that there is a $\eta_0>0$ and continuous vector field $X:(-\eta_0<f<\eta_0)\to\Bbb R^n$ such that $X(x)\cdot\nabla f(x)>\eta_0$ for almost every $x\in(-\eta_0<f<\eta_0)$. In your case $\Omega$ is convex the proof is easier:
W.l.o.g. $0\in\Omega$, take $\Omega_{\eta_0}=\bigcup\{B(x,\eta_0):B(x,\eta_0)\subset\Omega\}$, this is a $C^{1,1}$ domain. Take $X:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ be the unique vector field such that $X|_{\partial\Omega_{\eta_0}}$ is the unit outer normal vector field and $X(\lambda x)=X(x)$ for $\lambda>0$. Thus $X$ is a Lipschitz vector field (Lipschitz constant depends on $\eta_0$) and $X\cdot\nabla f>\eta_0$ is a neighborhood of $(f=0)$.
For $t<\frac{\eta_0}2$ we have $\phi_t\ast(X\nabla f)>\frac12\eta_0$ in the domain $(-\frac{\eta_0}2<f<\frac{\eta_0}2)$.
On the other hand the commutator estimate yields $\|\phi_t\ast(X\nabla f)-X\cdot(\phi_t\ast\nabla f)\|_{L^\infty}\lesssim_\phi t\|X\|_{C^{0,1}}\|\nabla f\|_{L^\infty}$. This can be done by direct computation:
\begin{align*}
    &\|\phi_t\ast (uv)-u\cdot(\phi_t\ast v)\|_{L^\infty}=\sup_x\Big|\int\phi_t(y)(u(x-y)-u(x))v(x-y)dy\Big|
\\
\le&\sup_x\|\nabla u\|_{L^\infty}\int|y\phi_t(y)||v(x-y)|dy\le\|\nabla u\|_{L^\infty}\|v\|_{L^\infty}\|y\phi_t(y)\|_{L^1_y}.
\end{align*}
So for small enough $t$, $X\cdot\nabla f_t>\frac14\eta_0$ on $(-\frac{\eta_0}2<f<\frac{\eta_0}2)$. In particular $df_t\neq0$.
If $\Omega$ is form by intersection of smooth hypersurface then $\Omega$ is always Lipschitz. $f$ is not exactly a sign distance but modifying by a constant would works.
For general bounded Lipschitz domain where we have inward cones, the domain $\Omega_{\eta_0}$ is given by $$\Omega_\eta=\bigcup \{B(x,\eta):B(x,\eta)\subset\Omega\}\cup\Big(B(0,R)\cap\big( \bigcup\{B(y,\eta):B(y,\eta)\subset\Omega^c\}\big)^c\Big).$$
Basically you "fill in the inner cones" a bit.

I am trying to understand the definition of $\delta$. Why do you write $\delta(x)=-d(x, \Omega)$ when $x\in \Omega$, in that case $d(x, \Omega)=0$ right? What you wrote isn't necessarily wrong, but seems odd you write it in that specific form. Also if I understand correctly, you're claiming after defining $\delta$ as that, where $\Omega={f=0}$, we get $f=\delta$? But this seems to be false, if I take $\Omega$ to be the simplex $\Delta^2$ and consider the point $(1,1)$ which is outside it and then the distance is $1/\sqrt{2}$ but $f(1,1)=-1$?

@ChanelRose Sorry it should be $\delta(x)=-d(x,\Omega^c)$. In this way $\Omega={\delta<0}$.

But you are right, in this case $f$ is $C^{1,1}$ outside the convex domain, but no just Lipschitz. Nevertheless if you set $f(x)=\min_i \alpha_i\cdot x+\beta_i$ such $f$ can still be called Lipschitz defining function of the domain $(f<0)$.

Thank you for your clarification, so $\delta$ may be a different function but $\delta<0$ defines the same subset as $f<0$. I have another question, how to choose $\eta_0$? It seems like one can always choose the subset $\Omega_{\eta_0}$ for any $\eta_0>0$. Also when you write $X\cdot \nabla f$ what does $\nabla f$ mean for a Lipschitz function?

Maybe this is a stupid question, but why is $\phi_t*(X\nabla f)>\eta_0/2$? I am also not familiar with the commutator estimate formula, could you refer to a theorem or a reference for that?

The choice of $\eta_0$ can be more clear if you draw some graph (it's not easy for a full proof I agree). A Lipschitz domain is locally a (upper of lower) part of a Lipschitz graph. So such $\eta_0$ depends on the Lipschitz constant of the graph and the size of local charts.

For your second question, the result simply follows from the assumption $X\nabla f>\eta_0$ almost everywhere. I don't have a reference but it's really standard let me write this proof.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
